# 'click' event retaining changes even after clicking is done

Tags: javascript, html

Why does the flexbox not turn back to black after a click is done? If I'm not wrong, the box should be blue just for an instance while using click event right? However the colour is permanently changed to blue. I am having a similar problem with mouseover event as well. Even after moving the cursor away from the flexbox, the colour does not change back to its original colour

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.flex');
a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    a.style.background = 'blue';
    console.log('click');
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The click event is fired, but doesn't stop or revert when the click is finished. If you want something to happen only while clicking, you might want to look into mousedown and mouseup events. You will have to specifically revert the change. Turn it blue on mousedown and then revert it on the mouseup. I would recommend adding and removing a class rather than directly updating the style.

Comment: Then what exactly is the difference between click and mousedown? Seems like they effectively do the same thing. Also , what exactly do you mean by adding and removing a class? I have also simplified the code.

Comment: Per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event), *click fires after both the mousedown and mouseup events have fired, in that order.*

Comment: ahh..so it's kinda like an && condition. So basically, 'click' is mousedown AND mouseup

Comment: Manav, it will help you greatly to understand the environment that is the browser.  This is scripting, and not programming. you register against events fired by the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element MDN is the GO TO place for web documentation, I highly recommend that you bookmark that site and refer to it and study it.  JS and browser has been a learning experience for me, I think you have the right attitude to make something great!  it's nothing like && condition, it completely independent, there is an established order to these events. Understand that to win!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event documentation, click event is fired after [mouseup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) and [mousedown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) events are triggered, so the click event won't trigger twice on the same click interaction.

If you need to change something on mouse down and up in the same click operation you need to handle 2 separate events.

Below i have put your script, enhanced with the double handler logic

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.flex');
a.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    a.style.background = 'blue';
    console.log('mousedown');
});
a.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
    a.style.background = 'black';
    console.log('mouse up');
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
}
.flex{
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex">
        
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```